# pass block as parameter in my case

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsthread, performselector

I have a function which takes a **block** as parameter:

```
typedef void (^ MyBlock)(int);

-(void)doTask:(MyBlock)theBlock{
 ...
}
```

I need to run above function on another thread, I want to use [- performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:) , my current code:

```
NSThread *workerThread = [[NSThread alloc] init];
[workerThread start];

[self performSelector:@selector(doTask:) 
             onThread:workerThread 
           withObject:???
        waitUntilDone:NO];
```

BUT, How can I pass `MyBlock` parameter with this approach? (Please don't suggest GCD, I am wondering how can I do with my current code, is it possible?)

Comment: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/

Comment: @Kreiri, have you read my question? The link has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Have you read the first line there?

Comment: I don't understand you, could you please directly say it out, and why downvote?

Answer (score 1):

*This answer assumes you are using ARC. If you are not then you need to do a little more, but overall the answer is the same.*

> BUT, How can I pass `MyBlock` parameter with this approach?

A block is an object, you don't need to do anything special. E.g.:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(doTask:) 
             onThread:workerThread 
           withObject:^(int arg){ NSLog(@"block passed: %d", arg); }
        waitUntilDone:NO];
```

HTH

Comment: Careful: A block becomes invalid once you leave the scope where it is declared, which happens if you store the block somewhere or execute it in a different thread. To avoid trouble you need to pass [MyBlock copy]. dispatch_async () for example will do this for you. That's also why block properties should be "copy". I doubt that performSelector would do this automatically.

Comment: @gnasher729 - You spotted the reason for the starting note. It has been a long time since block properties needed to be "copy" – *provided you use ARC*. The above example works fine, the compiler does what a compiler should – hides the on-stack optimisation and correctly moves the block to the heap when needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(someMethod) 
         onThread:[Your thread] 
       withObject:[your object]
    waitUntilDone:NO];

-(void)someMethod
{
   [self doTask:^(int intValue) {
        // Do your task
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, my case is this one, could you please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931737/initialize-start-nsthread-with-target-selector

Answer (score 0):

First create thread like this so that it is alive and you can call methods from that thread

```
-(void) myThreadMainMethod: (id) sender {

    @autoreleasepool {
        NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        [runloop addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

        while (true) { // add your condition for keeping the thread alive 
            [runloop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
        }
    }
}

  NSThread* workerThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                 selector:@selector(myThreadMainMethod:)
                                                   object:nil];

    [workerThread start];
```

Then write something like this

```
-(void)doTask:(MyBlock)theBlock{
        NSLog(@"do task called now execute the block");
        theBlock(1);
    }

    MyBlock block1 = ^(int a) {
        NSLog(@"integer %i", a);
    };

    [self performSelector:@selector(doTask:)
                 onThread:[NSThread mainThread]
               withObject:block1
            waitUntilDone:NO];
```